# Using np.multiply(out=array[mask]) does not work

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I tested the behavior of in-place operations with numpy. I observed the following:

```
test = np.arange(0, 10).reshape(2, 5)
mask = test > 5
```

This works

```
np.multiply(test, 3, out=test)

# Output: 
[[ 0  3  6  9 12]
 [15 18 21 24 27]]
```

but this

```
np.multiply(test[mask], 3, out=test[mask])

print(test)
# Output:
[[0 1 2 3 4]
 [5 6 7 8 9]]
```

doesn't. Why?

Comment: `test[mask]` alone returns a flat copy of what's in `test`. You would do `test[mask] = test[mask] * 3`.

Comment: but what if I want to do it in-place?

Comment: `test[mask] *= 3`?

Comment: Perhaps also possible: `np.multiply(test, 3, out=test, where=mask)`

Comment: while `test[mask] *= 3` does what it does, I really am not sure if it's in-place or still making a copy.

Comment: @Chrysophylaxs But that still multiplies the *whole* array, doesn't it? I want something that is fast and avoids any overhead.

Comment: @mozway This works for the example above, but not for more general cases with different data types (int vs. float e.g)

Comment: If you have to change the dtype, you'll have to rewrite the whole array anyway

Comment: The `where` in a `ufunc` is different from the `np.where` function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are some tests for comparison sake:

---

With few Truthy values in the mask:

```
import numpy as np

test = np.arange(100000)
mask = test < 100

%timeit np.multiply(test, 3, out=test, where=mask)
# 6.98 µs ± 90.2 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100,000 loops each)

%timeit test[mask] *= 3
# 21.3 µs ± 159 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100,000 loops each)

%timeit test[mask] = test[mask] * 3
# 21.9 µs ± 214 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)
```

---

with a lot of Truthy values:

```
test = np.arange(100000)
mask = test < 90000

%timeit np.multiply(test, 3, out=test, where=mask)
# 60.9 µs ± 554 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)

%timeit test[mask] *= 3
# 100 µs ± 474 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)

%timeit test[mask] = test[mask] * 3
# 120 µs ± 1.09 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)
```

---

with random mask:

```
test = np.arange(100000)
mask = np.random.choice([True, False], size=100000)

%timeit np.multiply(test, 3, out=test, where=mask)
# 411 µs ± 4.25 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)

%timeit test[mask] *= 3
# 712 µs ± 7.93 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)

%timeit test[mask] = test[mask] * 3
# 714 µs ± 5.72 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)
```

---

for completeness, without a mask:

```
%timeit np.multiply(test, 3, out=test)
# 22.4 µs ± 126 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)
```

---

so I would recommend `np.multiply` with `out=arr` and `where=mask`.